# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:HelloWorldApp

Tags: java, exception

a simple hello word program gets compiled but when I run it I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: a (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    Could not find the main class:HelloWorldApp.Program will exit.
```

I have java version 1.6.0_21

My program is:

```
class HelloWorldApp { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
   System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string. 
   }
}
```

Comment: how simple is this simple hello world program? can we see the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: My program is:class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compiled the `.class` for one version and tried to run it on an older version.

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Answer (score 2):

You compiled your Java code for one version of the Java JRE (e.g. version 7) but you ran it against an older version of the JRE (e.g. version 6).

To find out which version you have currently set up, you can open a shell or command prompt (in Windows) and type:

```
java -version
```

This will return the version number.

===edit===
*Adding more details to reply to the comment*
Java is a binary that comes from either the JRE or the JDK. There are different JRE/JDK providers out there, the main one being Oracle.

If you are on Windows, you can go to `C:\Program Files\Java` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` (32bit) and you will notice you have JRE folders and JDK folders. A JDK always contains a JRE. The JRE is the bare minimum you need to run a Java program. Normally, you always have the same JRE version as you do JDK version. To keep things simple, always develop and test against your JDK. Make sure you choose the right one.

How do you know which is in use? That's based on your environments variables. In a Windows command prompt you can write the following:

```
C:\Users\djob>set JA
```

and that will reply with

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
```

In that case you know which JRE is being used: the one that comes with the JDK 1.7.0u04. By the way, Java 7 is Java 1.7 (this is a Java convention) much like Java 6 is in fact Java 1.6.

Note that your IDE (e.g. Eclipse) may be set up with a different JRE so do check there as well.

HTH

Comment: So, is there any difference between jdk version and java version(which i saw in cmd)???

Comment: I added more details to the answer. I hope it covers all you need

Answer (score 0):

You run a class compiled in Java 7 with a Java 6 JVM

Answer (score 0):

The version of `class` file compiled with the newer version of Java. You need recompile your source code. If you can't recompile it or you don't have sources you can always upgrade to the new version of Java SE. Remember when you installed Java JDK or JRE there's always `jshed` process running and it always suggest you to do upgrade when the version of Java changes. All yo need is give it access to the internet, and once connected it will do its job, like magic.

Answer (score 0):

The java version compiled with not same as you set in JAVA_HOME